# How to adjust flash objects from all keyframes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

I know there has to be away to adjust objects on the stage from all keyframes because it's probably the most annoying thing I've experienced

I adjust a bitmap image and then when you play the movieclip, right when it hits another keyframe it shows the old position instead of the new. How can I update all images on the stage including all the keyframes?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to mix timeline animation/positioning and scripted positioning. Am I right? That's generally a bad idea. Try to stick to either all programmed animation, or all timeline-animation. If I'm wrong, please describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having 'fun' with stuff that is split between the two. Would be best to stick to one or the other, maybe apart from a few stops here and there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to toggle on "Edit multiple keyframes". Its the little switch next to the onion markers underneath the timeline. Looks like [ ] <-- that :). When you turn it on you will get these markers on your timeline that you can drag which will then show all the instances in the keyframes. Then you can select multiple keyframe items and apply the same transformations.

Answer (score 2):

In general when you make a change in one keyframe, the change occurs only in that keyframe. If you want a particular object (like a bitmap) to be unaffected by keyframes, simply move it to a different layer that has no keyframes. Then any adjustment you make to that bitmap will be reflected across the whole timeline. The whole principle of keyframes is that when they occur, the position, etc. of all objects in that keyframe are updated, so the key to working with the timeline is making sure that keyframes exist only in the places and only for the objects that need to be updated.